# Can't format hard drive

Tags: format

I'm trying to format my hard drive, and at the same time change it to GPT.
I'll replace ubuntu with windows so I'm okay with losing all the data :)

I searched disks, chose the main hard drive, format (GPT), 
Fail.
 Device is busy.

What to do?

Comment: Are you trying to format drive on which is system currently running?

Answer (score 1):

You need to unmount the Disk first. I think you're using `gparted`?

Select the disk

[image]

Right click and choose Unmount.

[image]

Note that to do this, the hard drive has to not be in use, i.e. you can't format the drive that Ubuntu / Windows is running on, while it's running.

To format the drive with Ubuntu, boot up with the Live CD or USB and chose to Try Ubuntu. Then you can format it.

Comment: It's letting me format, but I don't see GPT as a format option

Comment: Why do you want to format as GPT?

Comment: I can't install windows before changing the partition to GPT