# Install Ubuntu while emptying the alternative hard drive

Tags: boot, system-installation, hard-drive, ssd

I have one SSD and one HDD installed on my system. HDD contains my windows 10 installation. Now I want to install Ubuntu on SSD while completely clearing HDD, so that I can use that as a data storage unit.

On windows, I know how to do this, i.e. by going to custom installation and simply clicking the cross icon. But how do I do this in Ubuntu? (Installing on SSD while clearing HDD). Do I have to click the something else button while installing, if yes then what should I do?

I am a newbie in Linux, so detailed steps would be appreciated

Comment: You don't have to do "A while B" but you certainly can. But why? It's much easier to install Ubuntu and then, from the installed Ubuntu, re-format the drive you want. Or you can do it from the live session before installing, of course, it's almost the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing Ubuntu On Second Hard Drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/629750/installing-ubuntu-on-second-hard-drive) and [can't format hard drive](https://askubuntu.com/q/633351/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you certainly can do all of this during the installation, it may be simpler if you did it in two steps:

1. Install Ubuntu
2. Wipe the storage device

This would be the process:

0. From the installation process, choose "Erase disk and install Ubuntu
   [image: Installation type]

   Then press [Continue].
1. Select the device where you would like to install the OS
   [image: Where to go, where to go]

   Then press [Install Now].
2. You will be shown a confirmation message saying that the target storage device for the OS will be wiped clean
   [image: Are you sure?]

   So long as you're happy, press [Continue].
3. Let the system install itself. Depending on whether you elected to download updates or install 3rd-party drivers, this process may take a bit of time.

After Ubuntu is installed:

0. Open the "Disks" application
   [image: Disks]
1. Select the device that you want to use for storage, which will probably be NTFS formatted
   [image: Disks - Select Device]
2. If the disk is mounted, press the square "stop" button to the left under the volume block
3. Click the gears button and choose "Format Partition"
   [image: Disks - Format Partition]
4. Give the volume a name (if you wish), specify a type such as Ext4, then press the [Next] button in the upper-right corner
   [image: Disks - Volume Settings]
5. You'll see another confirmation message. So long as everything is correct, press the red "Format" button, enter your admin password.
6. Press the triangle "play" button to mount the volume so you can begin using it.

<sub>**Note:** Screenshots are from the Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS installer in a VirtualBox VM.</sub>